# Problem compiling DOOM source: error: initializer element is not constant (integer conversion)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to get the [original Doom code](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM) compiling.
I already fixed some errors but I don't know what this means. I'm not that good at C...

Example error (there are more errors, but they're the same):

```
m_misc.c:249:40: note: (near initialization for ‘defaults[16].defaultvalue’)
m_misc.c:250:42: error: initializer element is not constant
  250 |         {"mousetype", (int *)&mousetype, (int)"microsoft"},
      |                                          ^
```

As you can see it's marking the integer conversion.

This is the relevant part of the code. It's actually more, but it's repeating itself (more chat macro defining, etc.) so I shortened it a bit

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    int *location;
    int defaultvalue;
    int scantranslate; // PC scan code hack
    int untranslated;  // lousy hack
} default_t;

default_t defaults[] =
{
    {"mousedev", (int *)&mousedev, (int)"/dev/ttyS0"},
    {"mousetype", (int *)&mousetype, (int)"microsoft"},
    {"chatmacro0", (int *)&chat_macros[0], (int)HUSTR_CHATMACRO0},
    {"chatmacro1", (int *)&chat_macros[1], (int)HUSTR_CHATMACRO1},
};
```

I'm using gcc 10.1.0-2 under Linux.

Thanks in advance for any help:)

Comment: Try compiling with -m32. Does that fix it? If so, I will explain.

Comment: yep. it's working. can you explain? why isn't it working with 64 bit?

Comment: @hallowed In a nutshell, because the cast converts a pointer to an integer, and on 64 bit platforms a pointer is too large (= 64 bit) to fit into a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @hallowed And for complicated technical reasons, an expression that casts a pointer to an integer is considered to be a compile-time constant only if the cast does not change the value.

Comment: Thanks:) Couldn't I just use a long long?

Comment: Fixing the DOOM code to work correctly with 64-bit pointers is going to be a whole lot of work—this compile error is only the beginning. But there's only one integer type that's safe to cast pointers to: `uintptr_t`, declared in stdint.h. Use that.

Comment: I managed to get it compiling under 64 bit just using long longs. I'll change it. Thanks a lot.